# Java code Multiple Thread, Wait to start other

Tags: java

I a trying to find out, after complete first thread completely than start second thread, after complete second thread than start third thread, Please help me!!

Here is my code:

```
public class wait {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("First Thread");

        createtheard2();
    }

    public static void createtheard2() {

        try {

            System.out.println("Second Thread");

        } catch(Exception error1) {
            error1.printStackTrace();
        }

        createtheard3();
    }

    public static void createtheard3() {

        try {

            System.out.println("Third Thread");

        } catch(Exception error1) {
            error1.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

After complete first thread, than start second thread, after complete second thread, than start third thread, Please help me!! Thanks!!

Comment: If so, why you need thread? general theory is, we need to use threading if you want something get done without depending on other thread. Isn't it?

Comment: This was asked before.. . . searching now. . .

Comment: I am working on the program, To creating files first than, after all the file completely created than, run those file from other program so, that's why!! I am trying to do that way!! Please help, is there any other way to do that??

Comment: I think what you need is if task 1 (thread in your terms) success, run task2 else keep wait until task1 to finish. Am i right ?

Comment: Why not simple do everything on main thread (in a method with stream open), instead of using join?

Comment: @JayrajPatel If the files are independent, you don't need to wait for one to be created to create another. Launch all threads and wait for all of them to finish (see Thread#join()). If the files are dependent, you don't need threads. Please clarify yourself.

Comment: yap vels4j, you are right, that's what i am trying to do!! Please help me!! Thanks!! And Nambari, I tired that but its not working, whan run the program first time, it won't wait to completed those file!! and when i run the program second time than old file it created that run!! so, it won't wait to completed for all file to created in folder!! Please help me!! Thanks!!

Comment: Please post what you have tried, that helps us understand what might be going wrong. Without seeing code, it is hard to tell why it is failing.

Comment: What m0skit0 is saying is that if you want to create multiple files in parallel, starting them all and then waiting for the last one to finish, then you'll want to create and start one thread per file, and then (once they're all started) use Thread#join() to wait until they all complete.  If you want to create them serially (not in parallel), then you don't need threads, but if you have to use them (e.g. because this is a homework assignment and it's required), you can create and start one thread and use Thread#join() to wait for it to finish before starting the next one.

Answer (score 2):

1. Implement Runnable

   ```
   public class ThreadDemo implements Runnable {  
          public void run() {
             //Do this what you need
          }
   }
   ```
2. Use join to wait while thread will be completed.

   ```
   Thread t1 = new Thread(new ThreadDemo());
   // this will call run() function
   t1.start();
   // waits for this thread to die
   t1.join();

   Thread t2 = new Thread(new ThreadDemo());
   // this will call run() function
   t2.start();
   // waits for this thread to die
   t2.join();
   ```

From http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/join.html

> t.join() causes the current thread to pause execution until t's
>   thread terminates.

In your case paused by join method invocation thread will be Main thread.

Comment: This advice is as meaningful as advising how to push a fully functioning car to the destination instead of advising to sit behind the wheel and turn the key.

Comment: @mvb I think that you a showing a way to transform an async call into sync

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need is if task 1 (thread in your terms) success, run task2 else wait for task1. consider the following.

```
public class Process{

    public static void runProcess1() {

        boolean done = false;
        do {
            // make done=true after task1 is done
        } while (done);
        runProcess2();
    }

    public static void runProcess2() {

        boolean done = false;
        do {
            // make done=true after task2 is done
        } while (done);
        runProcess3();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        runProcess1();
    }
}
```

Comment: yap, that's what i am trying to do!! Please help me!! Thanks!!

Comment: That would not be a good idea. You're pretty much hardcoding stuff and it can easily become a nightmare later... You're better off using standard solutions; there are several approaches :)

Comment: I've given recipe, you have to cook.

Comment: @Powerslave Its an idea. Remember, always there are many way to reach a place. Someone have bike and I'm just cycling  :-)

Comment: dude, I tried that, its not working!!:( Please help me!! thanks!!

Comment: @vels4j Ah, I see. But, 'ey, who wants to have a bike that can only always turn left? ;) Basically, however, you're absolutely right as for this task, there is no need for `Thread`s, but for breaking down into subtasks represented by methods. The chain-invocation is a bit hackish though. You could simply call them sequentially :)

Answer (score 0):

As it was pointed out, using threads in this case does not make sense as you are executing tasks sequentially.

However, it is possible to have a single thread running at a time with [SingleThreadExecutor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newSingleThreadExecutor%28%29)

For example, you

1. Add your threads to a "todo list" (`ArrayList` will do the job)
2. Schedule a task (`ExecutorService.execute()`)
3. Wait for the scheduled task to complete (`Thread.join()`)
4. Drop the thread from the "todo list" `tasks.remove(currentTask);`
5. Pick the next task or go to step 7 if all has been finished
6. Go back to step 2
7. Kill the ExecutorService (`ExecutorService.shutdown()`)

Alternatively, you could use `ExecutorService.invokeAll()` using a single thread executor.

You could even simply run the tasks directly in a loop, invoking `start()`, however, I'd really recommend against using concurrency where it is not a necessity.